# Asio async handler is never called, no other handler invoked

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, boost-asio, unix-socket

I have a asio sync connection. ioService is in one thread (I have only one thread.).

**Smaller problem:**

```
boost::asio::async_write(m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(requestStr.data(), requestStr.size()), handler);
```

The handler is never called, but the server gets it and replies that I get.

**The bigger problem:**

```
boost::asio::async_read_until(m_socket, sbuf, '\n', sendingHandler);
```

It also doesn't call the handler. The **sbuf** is immediately filled and I can read it there, but I don't know the position of the deliminator. Therefore I need the handler to get the *bytes_transferred* parameter. (I'm not going to iterate the buffer.)

I tried several things and I could invoke the handler once, but I don't remember what the issue was about after a small refract. Any help? Thanks!

When I used sync messaging, everything was fine, but there is no timeout there.

EDIT:
If you know any nice solution to find the deliminator I don't need the handler.
Because, I would send the msg sync_write and read async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont be called, because it is **async**. Async methods for writing and reading never call handlers from within the place they're called:

> Regardless of whether the asynchronous operation completes immediately
>   or not, the handler will not be invoked from within this function.
>   Invocation of the handler will be performed in a manner equivalent to
>   using boost::asio::io_service::post().

You need to manually call io_service methods like `run` or `run_once` to perform operations and that is the moment when your callback will be called.